# Worklight v6: use multiple JSON stores concurrently in app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Is it possible to use two or more JSON stores in a Worklight app at the same time (without switching back and forth)?  When I initialize a second JSON store with a username/password, collections in the "default" JSON store that were initialized properly become inaccessible.

Given that many functions in the JSON store api does not let you specify a target store, I am guessing that using multiple stores concurrently is not possible.  If this is true, then how does one address the use case where it is necessary to:

1. Encrypt sensitive user data, and
2. Need access to non-sensitive data before user is authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username field you pass to init is basically the file name for the store, for example:

`WL.JSONStore.init(..., {username: 'store1'})`

You will have store1.sqlite on disk, no encryption. If you want to switch to another store simply call:

`WL.JSONStore.closeAll()`

The closeAll function will kill all database accessors. Then you can start a second store with a password, for example:

`WL.JSONStore.init(..., {username: 'store2', password: '123'})`

That will create a store2.sqlite file encrypted with 256-bit AES encryption.

If you want to switch back to store1, simply call `WL.JSONStore.closeAll()` and then `WL.JSONStore.init(..., {username: 'store1'})`.

Currently you can not access store1 and store2 at the same time. You can open a feature request [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

The .sqlite files are mentioned [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_jsonstore_support.html) if you want to see them on the file system, and a bit of their internal structure is mentioned [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_store_internals.html). The code snippets above don't show it, but make sure you take into account that most JSONStore API functions are async, read more [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_asynch_callbacks_promises.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think this kind of information should be in the official documentation, and there needs to be more examples.

Comment: @user2956676 It would be helpful if you explain what confused you or what you didn't understand from reading the official documentation. Did you read it all? There's [general docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html), [API docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_wl_jsonstore_core_api.html) and [example code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development). Feedback is appreciated.